# Нет линковки AesGcm WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, я делаю проект где использую `AesGcm` Класс в приложении `WinForms net.framework`, но как оказалось, в net.framework такого класса в пространстве `System.Security.Cryptography` нет, но вот если создаю WinForm на Core, то там он есть.
В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить, главным требованием должно быть что бы он принимал такие же параметры: `byte[] nonce, byte[] plaintext, byte[] ciphertext, byte[] tag, byte[]? associatedData = default`

```
associatedData - тоже используется
```

Я понял, что `AesGcm` нет, потому что он есть только в

```
.NET 5.0, 6.0 Preview 3
.NET Core 3.0, 3.1
.NET Standard   2.1
```

Comment: `В чем может быть проблема` - наверно в том, что старые версии особо не развиваются и не поддерживаются? Вы как программист должны держать весь софт в актуальном состоянии. `как ее исправить` - обновиться? Ну, либо ищите альтернативу (или сам этот пакет) в NuGet.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в принципе оно понятно, пришлось все переделывать на Core, минус в том, что кастомные фреймворки как Guna туда не ставятся.
Понял что луче WPF все таки

Comment: Если автор библиотеки не соизволил перенести свой проект хотяб под .NET Standard, то продукт явно заброшен, смысл тогда использовать то, что заброшено и не развивается? Что, будете сидеть допустим под .NET Framework 4, без кучи нововведений языка, лишь из-за того, что некий сторонний автор забил на свой продукт? Я бы не стал... По поводу UI - если хотите красиво, то это всегда был WPF.

Comment: Если либа хорошая, но автор ее бросил, наверняка кто-то уже ее форкнул и портировал на Core. Ну либо вы сами можете портировать, это не так сложно должно быть. Если либа - это коммерческий софт, то его надо срочно выбросить и заменить. Потому что если разработчик не актуализирует свой платный софт, то с разработчиком явно что-то не так, а значит и с софтом тоже.